# How to Pass the Angular Variable to Another Angular Google Chart Function(Angular Directive)

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-promise, google-visualization

Can someone help me in approach for passing Angular Variable to Google Chart Function which is present in the same Java Script with Angular Directive

And Also I wanted to load Google Charts to load only after passing the values.I just read some question they mentioned something like Promises How can i use here.

**Java Script**

In Below Code I wanted to pass Angular Variables openCount,closedCount  to Google Chart Function like with Angular JS

[**Demo For Google Chart with Angular JS**](http://jsbin.com/maluva/edit?html,js,output)

In the above Demo I am hard coding the values

```
"rows": [
        {c: [
            {v: "Defect Opened"},
            {v:1}
        ]},

        {c: [
            {v: "Defects Closed"},
            {v: 2}

        ]
```

Now instead of hard coding values I wanted to pass the values from below controller. How can I achieve this[What modification required for this]

```
var app = angular.module('defectApp', ["ngTable"]);
app.controller('defectController', [
    '$scope',
    '$http',
    function($scope, $http) {
        $http({method: 'POST', url: '/angular/defect/defect.php'}).success(function(response) {
            $scope.post = response;

            console.log(response);

            var openCount = $filter('filter')(response.data, {status: 'Open'}).length,
            closedCount = $filter('filter')(response.data, {status: 'Closed'}).length,
            assignedCount = $filter('filter')(response.data, {status: 'Assigned'}).length;

            console.log(openCount);
        })
    },
]);
```

Comment: when you call `drawSarahChart`?

Comment: I wanted to call after assigning the values to `openCount,closedCount`

Comment: can't you pass `openCount` and `closedCount` to `drawSarahChart` in `controller` after  `openCount` and `closedCount` get assigned?

Comment: No Because I need to pass this function into Google Chart as below later
`google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});

      // Draw the pie chart for Sarah's pizza when Charts is loaded.
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawSarahChart);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to introduce a [service](https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.21/docs/guide/services) and move the method for getting data from `defectController` into service:

```
.service('defectService', function ($http, $filter) {
    return {
        getInfo: function () {
            return $http({ method: 'POST', url: '/angular/defect/defect.php' })
                .then(function (response) {
                    return {
                        "openCount": $filter('filter')(response.data, { status: "Open" }).length,
                        "closedCount": $filter('filter')(response.data, { status: 'Closed' }).length,
                        "assignedCount": $filter('filter')(response.data, { status: 'Assigned' }).length
                    }
                });
        }
    };
})
```

Then inject `defectService` service info chart contoller. Modify chart controller to draw a chart once the data is retrieved:

```
.controller("chartCtrl", function ($scope, defectService) {

    defectService.getInfo()
        .then(function (info) {
            console.log(info);
            $scope.drawChart(info);
        });


    $scope.drawChart = function (info) {
        //code is omitted for clarity..
    };


});
```

[**Demo**](https://plnkr.co/edit/N2Lvm70T1NUOig1zuvcz?p=preview)

Comment: Worked like a charm well explained and Thanks for the demo :)

Comment: I am finding little trouble with my defect.json Can you please help me with this
`{
  "data": [
    {
      "type": "defect",
      "id": 1,
      "user-01": "John",
      "status": "Closed",
      "severity": "1 - Urgent"
    },
    {
      "type": "defect",
      "id": 4,
      "user-01": "John",
      "status": "Closed",
      "severity": "4 - Medium"
    },
    {
      "type": "defect",
      "id": 5,
      "user-01": "John",
      "status": "Open",
      "severity": "4 - Medium"
    }
  ]
}`

this is the real structure of my defect.json

Comment: Sure, here is an [updated plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/N2Lvm70T1NUOig1zuvcz?p=preview). Key point: `$filter` function which expects an array for the first parameter, it should be `response.data.data` since `response.data` corresponds to response body and `data` root element